# How to export all attributes of a DOORS module

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to send all possible attributes of a DOORS module, which is quite large. How can I easily send my colleague all attributes of the DOORS module, so that he can tell which attributes he wants to be exported to him?

I'm looking for an out-of-the-box solution, which does not require an DXL script or something complex. I just don't want to send a bunch of screenshots to my colleague, as there are really plenty of attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would indeed be a DXL script that prints all attributes. It's not even complicated, it only depends on which information you want to give to your colleague. If you only need the name of the attributes, open the module, start Tools->Edit DXL (from the Module explorer, not the database explorer!) and paste the following.

```
AttrDef ad
print "object specific attributes:\n"
for ad in current Module do { if (ad.object) {print ad.name ","}}
print "\n\n"

print "module specific attributes: \n"
for ad in current Module do { if (ad.module) {print ad.name ","}}
print "\n\n"
```

Depending on your needs you might want to change the condition to `if (ad.object and !ad.system)`, which will filter out all variables that DOORS provides per default, like Created By, TableCellWidth etc. Also, you might want to print out additional information like ad.typeName (the type of the attribute) or ad.description.

Comment: Many thanks for this nice and throughrough explaination. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to add DXL scripts due to missing rights, as I'm working on a customer system.

Comment: I fear it will be screenshots then. I looked through the GUI again and found no built in feature that allows sth like a "select all columns" (in File->Export) or a "print list" or sth. like that. The best that I could find was right click on the headings -> New (Column) -> Attribute -> click on list. this shows 30 attributes, so at least the number of screenshots is a bit reduced

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but thought I would add a comment here for people searching in the future.

1. If the user isn't using the same doors database as you, you can export your project partition to include the module they need. They can import the partition, open a module they want to import the attributes to, go to the Edit -> Types function and click Import. Choose the imported partition module and select the Attribute Types you need. You can do the same for the Attributes after (do the Types first!). Remove partitions etc.
2. If they have access to the same Doors database, simply go to the Edit -> Types function and click Import. Choose the source module and select the Attribute Types you need. Do the same for the Attributes afterwards.